# ¿Cómo puedo obtener valores en una columna de visualización de tabla pero filtrados en Power B?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Estoy aprendiendo Power BI y tengo nula experiencia en DAX, tengo que hacer un reporte donde me muestre los valores a partir de un filtro A y filtro B pero de un mes (digamos Marzo) para presentarlo en una visualización de tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muestro aquí un ejemplo ficticio porque no puedo mostrar datos de la empresa donde trabajo, pero básicamente necesito obtener los valores de un País en específico, de un mes en específico y mostrarlos por cada valor C y D en la tabla.

He leído que con CALCULATE y FILTER puedo hacerlo, pero el problema es que cuando lo hago me salen valores repetidos en mi columna, no sé por qué sucede esto.